# Is it possible to detect ASP Session State Type from code?

Tags: vb.net, session-state

I'm trying to track down a problem on our test environment.  Previously it was set to use InProc Session State Type, but I've added in the SQLServer type for one specific Web App.  I did this because we use the SQLServer type in our production environment and I want our test env to match as closely as possible.

However, after changing it to SQLServer I do not get any errors when trying to store unserializable data in session like I would expect.  It works just fine, even though I would think it shouldn't.  I'm a relative newbie when it comes to configuring this, but from the various tutorials I googled, I thought I covered all the bases.

I was wondering if there's any code snippets to verify which session state type an application is actively using.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it by accessing:

```
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.Mode
```

Was also able to look at the tables in the ASPState database to see sessions being added/removed.

Apparently it was just the test code we were using that we expected to break that was not behaving as we expected..